# Paypal integration for mobile apps

Tags: paypal

I'm developing an app using mobile jquery and my plan is to convert it to a android app using phonegap. I have integrated paypal payments to the app. 
My problem is how can I redirect to the mobile app from the server once the payment is accepted or cancelled ?

Comment: Redirect what? Won't the payment originate from the app?

Comment: I'm using mobile jquery. So I use the traditional data posting method to paypal.

Comment: And why would this not work from the mobile app?

Comment: Is jquery mobile not carried over with phonegap?

Comment: I have completed the app until the payment. After that, paypal redirect to a php file which is defined by me inside the server. So I need to come back to the mobile app from that php file. Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: So The question is how get the mobile app access to the php file that PayPal sent some final decision? Or how to set up app to be the endpoint instead of the current php endpoint?

Comment: Yes the question is how get the mobile app access to the php file that PayPal sent some final decision?

Comment: how does the non mobile app do it?